# Props return undefined ( React )

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to access my `props.group` in my `ViewGroup` component, but my props return `undefined`

I tried with a constructor but it's producing the same `undefined`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDoVD.png)

**ViewGroup.js**

```
class ViewGroup extends React.Component{

render() {
    console.log(this.props.group, ' CONSOLE LOG PROPS GROUP')
    return(
        <div style={styles.base}>

        </div>
       )
   }  
 }
```

**DataGroup Component**

```
import ViewGroup from './ViewGroup'

class DataGroup extends React.Component{

render(){
    const { dataGroups } = this.props
    return(
        <div>
            <ViewGroup
                group={dataGroups}
            />

        </div>
    )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const dataGroups = state.groupReducer.group ? state.groupReducer.group :[]
   return {
     dataGroups
    }
   };
  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DataGroup)
```

**Actions.js**

```
  export function loadGroup(data){ return { type: LOAD_GROUP, data }};

  export default function groupReducer( state= {}, action = {}){
  switch (action.type){
    case LOAD_GROUP:
        return {
            ...state,
            group: action.data
        }
    default:
        return state
    }
   }
```

**Reducer**

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
 Auth,
 groupReducer,
 persistStore,
 form: formReducer
});
```

Comment: Post all of your code. E.g. reducers, etc.

Comment: @Colin, Yes it's good i'have add everything. my component dataGroup return correctly my data "group" of my action. I want just to send ma data group in my component viewgroup

Comment: I think this: `const dataGroups = state.groupReducer.group ? state.groupReducer.group :[]` should actually be: `const dataGroups = state.group ? state.group :[]`. Can you post where you combine your reducers?

Comment: did you checked the signature of loadGroup action in mapDispatchToProps ?

Comment: @Colin, i have add my combineReducers. I just saw that when I am on the url of the component "dataGroup" the props function well so "viewgroup" recupere well the props. But when I go on the url of my "dashboard" everything is undefined but I call well "viewGroup" in my component "dashboard"

Comment: in fact i just want a parent component that distributes data to child components

Comment: yes i do @LefiTarik, the same thing directly in the viewgroup component works fine, but I wanted a parent component to distribute the data to the child component to avoid repeating the same request

Answer (score 0):

I think this: `const dataGroups = state.groupReducer.group ? state.groupReducer.group :[]` should actually be: `const dataGroups = state.group ? state.group :[]`.